# Props change after set data with splice

Tags: vue.js

So I get prop data, like that:

```js
props: {
  array: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
},
```

And I have to declare 2 arrays 1st - actual one after markup, 2nd - previously before markup.

So...
to do that i did something like that, inside method:

```js
checkExist() {
  const newArray = []
  const arr = this.array[this.counter].splice(1)
  arr.map(el => {
    !newArray.includes(el) ? newArray.push(el) : false
  })
  return newArray
},
```

So now I got `array[x]` without 1st item,
and it works like a charm :D

but... if counter will be more than 0, I will have to add some extra checks, so I need to know what was inside array before mapping.

```
this.beforeSelect = this.array[this.counter - 1];
```

returning 1st item with index 0 from array because actual array use splice(1). 
1st item is a title.

So, now, how to get to the point?

should i change that?

```
const arr = this.array[this.counter].splice(1);
```

but for what?

without `.splice(1)`, everything works perfect... but I need `splice`.
 any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First, using splice is actually mutating your original array that you're passing as a prop. You never want to mutate props in a child. If you want to change the original array that you're passing as a prop, this should happen in the parent component.

If you want to create a local copy of that array you could use

```
const arr = this.array[this.counter].slice()
```

This will create a local copy, that you can modify to your liking without mutating the original. Then you can continue remove the first index by splicing your local copy.

Comment: that one wont work eather xD  but i create next value and slice const arr not array xD